# rails -version command error in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed ruby and rails in Ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to create the new project for rails using this command "rails new testApp", but it is giving me the error "/home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rails-4.2.0/bin/rails (LoadError)". It is so ugly and pathetic to run the rails in windows so i switched to Ubuntu but here I am again facing difficulties.

Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: This might be more applicable on Ask Ububtu (http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: What's the "rails -version command error"?

Comment: No one is there to answer my question???

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' when ever i try to run the command related to rails it gives me the error i mentioned above , like i want to create the new project using "rails new simpleApp" it also gives me the same error.But when i download the app code from internet it is wroking and i can run the server by using this command "rails server".But when i try to  create new app using the "rails new testApp" command it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i resolved this problem myself because there are no experts i think in domain of ruby on stack overflow but any way i resolved the problem by  following the instructions mention below.

1. Uninstalled the rails 
2. Uninstalled the ruby
3.Then installed the latest version of ruby using rvm command

> rvm install ruby 2.1

4.Then installed the rails using command gem install rails.

**It started working**

Anyway thanks @johnny and @Mike